# How to Access method variable , outside the method in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want Access local variable outside the method?
for ex:

```
$(document).ready(function {
    $('#id').click(function() {
        var id = 10;
    });
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: something like this `var id = 0;
$('#id').click(function() {
 id = 10;
});
alert(id);` should work

Comment: It Just print 0 all time

Comment: [check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j8yoajtp/1/) i made the click event click on load

Comment: yes it works thanks

Comment: glad it helps happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a variable outside the scope in which it is declared. In order to access it outside the handler, you need to declare it outside like:

```
$(document).ready(function {
    var id = 0;
    $('#id').click(function() {
        id = 10;
    });
    alert(id);
});
```